# Need help with missing pics!

Tags: files

I recently uploaded over one hundred photos from my camera into Shotwell and I got the message that they were successfully uploaded, deleted from my memory card and then when I went to view the pics they were not there. In shotwell it is saying that my last import was on Mar 30 when it was actually Apr 13. Please help!

Comment: Visit home/pictures

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the import went wrong ...

Did you already use the SD card again?
If not then there are some tools around that could (with some luck) recover the deleted files from the card.
Just make sure you write block (lock) the SD card until you found your photos.

This might be helpful http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: I am so grateful! Used photorec last night and was able to get all of my children's Easter pics back. Thank you!!